# Passing CoreData NSManagedObjects to a subview

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I want to pass on an NSManagedObject (or an Array of those) from CoreData to a subview.
Is it correct, to pass the NSObject as Binding?

```
struct Main View {  
  @ObservedObject var item : Item
  // some code
  SubView(tags: $item)  
}

struct SubView {  
  @Binding var item : Item
  // some code
}
```

or is it better to pass the NSObject directly and declare it as @ObservableObject in the Subview?

```
struct Main View {  
  @ObservedObject var item : Item
  // some code
  SubView(tags: item)  
}

struct SubView {  
  @ObservedObject var item : Item
  // some code
}
```

Trying it with the "ObservableObject-Way", I get a problem, when I want to pass a to-many relationship to the Subview.

```
struct Main View {  
  @ObservedObject var item : Item
  // some code
  SubView(tags: $item.tags)   // tags is an array, containig the related
                              // NSObjects Tag
}

struct SubView {  
  @ObservedObject var tags : [Tag]  // Does not compile
  // some code
}
```

**@ObservedObject var tags : [Tag]** does not compile with the error:
Generic struct 'ObservedObject' requires that '[Tag]' conform to 'ObservableObject.
Tag is a NSManagedObject, how can an Array of NSManagedObjects be passed to the SubView?

Comment: An array is not an `ObservableObject`, each tag might be but you can't observe the entire array. you can just use `var tags : [Tag]`, no wrapper and then wrap each tag

Comment: How can I wrap each tag, if I declare var tags : [Tag] with no wrapper?

Comment: With a subview, and a ForEach you wrap in the subview

Comment: is the variant with ObservedObject or with Binding the better one? Is there a substantial difference?

Comment: `Binding` is for value types, `ObservedObject` is for reference types that are `ObservableObject`s